# Adding calculated row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

```
gender math score   reading score   writing score           
female    65                73           74
male      69                66           64
```

Given the dataframe (see above) how can we add a line that would calculate the difference between the row values in the following way :

```
gender      math score    reading score   writing score         
female         65               73            74
male           69               66            64
Difference     -3                7            10
```

Or is there a more convenient way of expressing the difference between the rows?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Please see [ask].  It helps provide context to the question.

Comment: `df.loc['difference'] = df.sub(df.shift(-1)).iloc[0]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a one-liner with `.loc[]` and `.diff()`:

```
df.loc['Difference'] = df.diff(-1).dropna().values.tolist()[0]
```

Another idea would be to work with a transposed dataframe and then transpose it back:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'gender':['male','female'],'math score':[65,69],'reading score':[73,66],'writing score':[74,64]}).set_index('gender')
df = df.T
df['Difference'] = df.diff(axis=1)['female'].values
df = df.T
```

Output:

```
            math score  reading score  writing score
gender                                              
male              65.0           73.0           74.0
female            69.0           66.0           64.0
Difference         4.0           -7.0          -10.0
```

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if it helped you and let me know of any questions ! :)

Answer (score 3):

Let -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[5, 10], "B":[9, 8], "gender": ["female", "male"]}).set_index("gender")
df.loc['Difference'] = df.apply(lambda x: x["female"]-x["male"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the diff by selecting each row and then subtracting. But as you've correctly guessed, that is not the best way to do this. A more convenient way would be to transpose the df and then do subtraction:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[65, 73, 74], [69, 66, 64]], 
                  index=['female', 'male'], 
                  columns=['math score', 'reading score', 'writing score'])

df_ = df.T

df_['Difference'] = df_['female'] - df_['male']
```

This is what you get:

```
               female  male  Difference
math score         65    69          -4
reading score      73    66           7
writing score      74    64          10
```

If you want you can transpose it again `df_.T`, to revert back to it's initial form.